# View the total number of media added by a user

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a function that returns the total number of media uploaded by a user, but I would like to see the number of media loaded by the user logged in `($user_ID = get_current_user_id ();)`

**My code:**

```
 function um_galleria_get_photos_count( $user_id = 0 ) 
{
global $wpdb;
$count = $wpdb->get_var(
$wpdb->prepare(
"SELECT COUNT(id) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}um_galleria WHERE user_id=%d",
$user_id
)
);
return $count;
}
```

How can I take from the database the total number of multimedia contents uploaded by the user connected `$user_ID = get_current_user_id (); ?`

Comment: A little confused... you wrote the function but don't know how to pass the value into it?  `$total = um_galleria_get_photos_count(get_current_user_id ());`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply Sorry but I don't speak English well and I explained myself wrongly. The function is already present in the downloaded plugin (the one written above), but it doesn't do what I want. I would like user_id to always call user_id of the user who logged in and I don't know how to change the function. I hope I was more precise. Thank you.

Comment: I don’t know WordPress, but the function accepts whatever user if you send to it, so you should be able to pass any user id to it. Since get_current_user_id() returns the id of the logged in user, the code snippet in my previous comment should work. If my tiny bit of research was accurate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Media are a kind of post type - so you can use WP_query posts. I have this code which is working for me try it once.

```
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id(); 
    $args = array(
      'post_type'      => 'attachment',
      'author'         =>  $user_id,
      'posts_per_page' => -1 // no limit
    );
    echo count(get_posts($args));
}
```

if your are getting data from a custom table or plugin tables then just override the user_id parameter to the current logged in user ID.
In your case just override the answer

```
function um_galleria_get_photos_count( $user_id = 0 ) 
     {
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        global $wpdb;
        $count = $wpdb->get_var(
        $wpdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}um_galleria WHERE user_id=%d", $user_id));
        return $count;
    }
```

Comment: Does that supported on latest WordPress version?

Comment: Tested on Wordpress 5.1

Comment: I did like the fact that this does not directly run any query, and just uses existing methods, like `get_posts()`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replies. Sorry, I don't speak English well and I explained myself wrongly. The function is already present in the downloaded plugin (the one written above), but it doesn't do what I want. I would like user_id to always call user_id of the user who logged in and I don't know how to change the function. I hope I was more precise. Thank you.

Comment: so just override the user ID.
add this ( $user_id = get_current_user_id();  ) at the top of the function to override the user_id variable it always get the current logged in user id. just remember the variable name should be the same as the parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried, but it doesn't work. If I log in with a user who has uploaded 3 photos (for example), it doesn't show me anything.

Comment: use die() and debug it in every part in the this function but first make sure you are in the correct file and this is the correct function to edit. also make sure to check if the user id this table much to the user ids on the WP_user table.